# Responsive CSS works on regular browsers, not on mobile... why?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to put together a simple portfolio site, and have implemented a basic responsive design into the CSS as well (at the very bottom of it), and it behaves just fine - shrinks the 5 columns down to a single column and hides a few elements when I resize the computer browser. But on iPhone/Android browser it doesn't make any difference.

Here is the page in question -> [Sample Page](http://tinyurl.com/a29hqlo)

And I can't figure out what the issue is... as in, this should be fairly simple to do, but apparently it's not, and now I'm losing sleep over it... so might as well ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you [also] consider the use of viewport meta-tag? Just check [This](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/mobifying/).

Comment: weird, but that kinda solved it... adding a few of those meta tags. will have to test on a few more devices, but that worked! thanks.

Comment: Did you solve the problem and what did you did? in the link provided by Andy there is a ;ot of different meta tags, which one did you use?

Answer (score 0):

I tried loading the site but it seems like your custom js file is not found(404 error).

Comment: sorry, try now. minor oversight.